# txt file (supposedly containing 10-digit telephone numbers) validity check

Tags: ksh

Given a txt file containing 10-digit telephone number each line, like:

```
2012176801
3019482395
4804432389
6094036369
8455614812
9175218198
...
```

This is the ideal format. Is there a way in ksh to detect any line that is shorter/longer, and/or, there is some characters other than pure digits? Like the following:

```
2012176801
301
4804432389
609abc
8455614812488
9175218198
...
```

Is there a way in ksh to detect line 2, 4, 5 in this txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`egrep -vn '^[[:digit:]]{10}$' phones.txt` will find all lines that do **NOT** consist of 10 digits. The -n flag prints line numbers. The -v flag is the one that searches for lines not matching the expression. You have to use egrep because regular GNU grep does not understand the curly brace notation.

Comment: Simple and elegant, Mad. Thanks a lot. By the way, is there also a way to detect duplicate 10-digit telephone numbers in the same file?

Comment: Add `| sort | uniq -d` to the above command to print duplicated lines.  You can omit the `| sort` if your file is already sorted. Leave out the `-d` option to output the list of numbers with duplicates removed.

Comment: Yes, `sort phones.txt | uniq -cd` will print the repeated lines. `sort phones.txt | uniq - phones.txt.unique` will create a new file with only the unique numbers